# Плавная анимация нажатия кнопки

Tags: android

Есть к примеру кнопка серого цвета. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на неё, она плавно становилась красной, а при отпускании красный цвет плавно исчезал, и она опять становилась серой?

Comment: а пример есть этого?

Comment: Так пример нужен мне, чтобы реализовать кнопку.. Ну типа как через shape задать цвета, только там при нажатии и отпускании резко меняет цвет кнопка, а надо чтобы плавно по альфаканалу что-ли..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Это пример.

**values/colors.xml:**

```
<color name="red">#ff0000</color>
<color name="gray">#a9a9a9</color>
```

**xml activity/fragment(a):**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**activity/fragment:**

```
final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_hello);

button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(button, "backgroundColor" /*view attribute name*/, new ArgbEvaluator(), getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.gray) /*from color*/, getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red) /*to color*/);
                colorFade.setDuration(1000);
                colorFade.setStartDelay(200);
                colorFade.start();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(button, "backgroundColor" /*view attribute name*/, new ArgbEvaluator(), getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red) /*from color*/, getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.gray) /*to color*/);
                colorFade.setDuration(1000);
                colorFade.setStartDelay(200);
                colorFade.start();
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при первом нажатии на кнопку при первом запуске программы, она резко становится красной и погасает, а только потом уже работает корректно? Можете это подправить в коде? И будет то что надо..

Comment: Вроде получилось, убрал <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

Comment: Обновил ответ, там получилось что вообще можно без селектора, главное по умолчанию бэкраунд задайте нужным цветом

Comment: Первый раз получается срабатывал селектор, где был true. И получалось вроде как, что он срабатывал раньше анимации.. А почему после этого уже работало как нужно, хороший вопрос

Comment: А вот еще интересует если можно, как сделать, чтобы когда пальцем съезжаешь с кнопки, чтобы тоже срабатывало исчезание красного? А то тут пока с экрана палец не отпустишь, то остается красным.. Это мелочь, но если можно, то хотелось бы сделать..

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под "съезжаешь" с кнопки?

Comment: Когда нажмешь на кнопку, и не отпуская ее ведешь вниз, то когда палец выходит за пределы кнопки, хотелось бы, чтобы срабатывало исчезновение красного..

Comment: case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                        currX = event.getRawX();
                        currY = event.getRawY();


                        float viewLeft = v.getLeft();
                        float viewRight = v.getRight();
                        float viewTop = v.getTop();
                        float viewBottom = v.getBottom();

                        if (currX < viewLeft || currX > viewRight || currY < viewBottom || currY > viewTop) {
                           ...
                        }
                    }

Comment: Большое спасибо.. Сделал по аналогии.. Вроде работает, правда если плавно съехать с кнопки, вроде красный цвет плавно погасает, но при отпускании пальца кнопка снова становится красной и опять плавно исчезает цвет.. Видимо надо изобретать какие-то флаги, чтобы MotionEvent.ACTION_UP не срабатывало, если MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE уже сработало...

Comment: правильно думаете, флаги нужны. но там нужно будет почитать про inner классы, так как из внешнего класса, вы можете пользоваться только свойствами помеченными как final.